# Why use CONSTRAINT?

Tags: sql, constraints

We define foreign key like this `FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES User(name)` or something like this. Why and when do we need to use constraint? I don't quite get the purpose of constraint.

Comment: What are you proposing as an alternative? That you just put any old data in the column and *hope* it refers to an ID in another table?

Comment: Not sure that a user who doesn't know that a constraint enforces the relationship would be in a position to nominate an alternative enforcement method. . .

Comment: answerable with a very quick internet search.

Comment: If you don't give a constraint such as a foreign key, a primary key, a unique constraint or a check constraint a name, the DBMS creates a name for you. Most likely, it includes the constraint name in the error information when the constraint is violated. If you choose the constraint name, it may make the raw error messages more meaningful. You may also be able to drop constraints by name.
However, raw error messages should not be presented to end users, though they might legitimately appear in application log files. (If this is what you asked about, your question could have been clearer!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the constraint on the foreign key is to ensure that you cannot delete the record in the main table while there are still references to it in other tables. If there was no constraint you would get invalid data in your database and the referential integrity would be violated.

Comment: @DarinDimitrow: Foreign keys are not enough for that?

Comment: A foreign key IS a constraint.  Are you talking about CHECK constraints?

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the constraint (including PRIMARY KEYs, FOREIGN KEYs, and CHECK constraints) is to instruct the database engine to enforce certain facts about your data.

For instance, if you have a table `customers` and a table `orders` and both tables have a column `customer_id` it is probably true that it is an illegal condition to ever record an order with a `customer_id` that does not exist in the `customers` table.

If so, you can declare the `customer_id` in `customers` to be a PRIMARY KEY and the `customer_id` in `orders` to be a FOREIGN KEY that REFERENCES the PRIMARY KEY in `customers`.  Once you make that declaration, the database engine will reject any SQL statement that would create a violation of that relationship (you could not DELETE a `customer` that had `orders`, create an `order` for a non-existent `customer`, and so on).

Using constraints is *far* superior to simply enforcing the logic in the application level because it *guarantees* that illegal data will never enter your system regardless of what application or user interface is used to access the database.  If you enforce your relational integrity at the application level you must hope that future interfaces to the database enforce the logic consistently and correctly, and you will not be able to enforce the logic in generic applications that allow direct access to the database tables.